# Will CocoaPods auto import frameworks into my own project?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm new to Cocoapods.

I created a project with Podfile like following:

```
platform :ios, '5.1'
pod 'MKNetworkKit'
```

After `pod install`, I compiled my project, but it reported errors.

Then I found the solution that it should set `SystemConfiguration.framework` in `Build Phases -> Link Binary with Binaries`.

My question is:

There is`SystemConfiguration.framework` in `Pods` Target, and I have `libpods.a` in my own project, shall I must include frameworks again in my own project target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaPods will automatically link to a framework if the library declares that it requires that framework. It *should* not be necessary to iclude the framework manually. There must be another problem causing this.

Update: For current versions of CocoaPods, if installing a library that contains an embedded framework, it seems not to link automatically. . . I don't know how to fix this. Please provide a new answer if you do.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check again.

Comment: Any  luck finding the answer? I'm seeing the same issue in my project.